# Catching an exception and clearing it before ELMAH gets it

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, elmah

I have a problem where I have an exception being thrown that I am capturing in Global.asax. As part of this exception handling I redirect the user to a specific page because of this exception.

I also have ELMAH error handling with the email module plugged in. I do not want to receive emails for this exception. I also don't want to add this type of exception to ELMAHs ignore list, in case I want to do granular work around the exception (i.e., only if it matches certain properties, happens on certain pages)

I want to:

- write an `Application_OnError` that
  redirects a user to a page (I know how to do this part, more for procedure I've left it here)
- in the `Application_OnError` stop ELMAH from
  receiving this error after I've caught it

I am currently calling `Server.ClearError()` inside my `App_OnError` method, but am still receiving these emails.

Comment: I want to do it globally, not inside a controller method

Comment: I know this is obvious and kind of trite, but maybe if you know what the exception is, can you fix the problem rather then just ignore it? If it's in an external library or something that you are forced to use, I get it, but there is probably a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [ELMAH documentation](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering)

I put leave my `Application_OnError` method in my Global.asax but I also add the following global methods:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    Filter(args);
}

void ErrorMail_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    Filter(args);
}

void Filter(ExceptionFilterEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Exception.GetBaseException() is HttpRequestValidationException)
    {
        args.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

What this does is dismiss the ELMAH exception if it is the type that matches what I want - in my case the `HttpRequestValidationException`.

The `ErrorMail_Filtering` method is only required if you have the error mail filter turned on - which I do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `[HandleError]` attribute as well? The way I would do is:

1. Create a custom `HandleError` attribute for action level and will not apply the attribute on the action where I don't want to get ELMAH involved.
2. The `Application_Error` code will exists as is.

Comment: what do you mean "action level"

Comment: sajoshi means place the attribute at the action level, as in on the action, not the controller, assuming this only happens on specific actions not within your entire codebase.